# Django: no such column ecomapp_toplist.desc - can anyone find error

Tags: python, django

why `no such column: ecomapp_toplist.desc`
is showing because I make desc in the model and register it also.

```
class TopList(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProductImg')
    title = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    discountpercentage = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    discountPrice = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    brandName = models.TextField(max_length = 100 , default='',null=True,blank=True)
    finalprice = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category , on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_all_categories():
        return Category.objects.all()
```

my `admin.py` by

```
@admin.register(TopList)
class TodoListModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['id','image','title','category' ]
```

Comment: did you forget to makemigrations and migrate

Comment: no i did both makemigrations and migrate

Comment: did you do fake migrate. if no then check go to your database management console and check the column existis by running select * from ecomapp_toplist;

Answer (score 0):

if you have added `desc` field after migration, then use this:

```
desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)

# insted of 
desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
```

Then again do makemigrations and migrate.